# Notepad++ Can not Restore Previous Session

Tags: notepad++

I had 20 saved files and 5 unsaved files in Notepad++, while working.

I restarted Windows 10 and started Notepad++.

Notepad++ is now empty. Previous session is not there.

I gone to AppData/Notepad++/backup folder. The files are there.

How can I bring back the previous session please in proper way?

Notepad++ 7.2.1, Windows 10

Session.xml is like this:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <Session activeView="0">
        <mainView activeIndex="0" />
        <subView activeIndex="0" />
    </Session>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to visit this [page.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675202/notepad-setting-for-disabling-auto-open-previous-files)

Answer (score 1):

For versions 6.6+ you need to `CHECK` -"Remember the current session for next launch" on Settings -> Preferences -> Backup.

[image: pic1]

For older versions you need to `CHECK` - "Remember the current session for next launch" on Settings -> Preferences.

[image: pic2]

If it's check, Try finding the recovery folder of Notepad++. On my XP machine (If it exist in your PC), it is at

`C:\Documents and Settings\<user account name>\Local
  Settings\Temp\N++RECOV`

The path may start differently in other versions of Windows.

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675202/notepad-setting-for-disabling-auto-open-previous-files)

I would suggest to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win)

Comment: Thanks. I have Notepad++ 7.2.1. Setting is already checked. Backup folder is there. No N++RECOV folder though. Updated question.